# Project Euler 9 Understanding

Tags: math, pythagorean

This question states:

> A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a b c, for which,
>
> a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup>
>
> For example, 3<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5<sup>2</sup>.
>
> There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.
> Find the product abc.

I'm not sure what's it trying to ask you. Are we trying to find `a2 + b2 = c2` and then plug those numbers into `a + b + c = 1000`?

Comment: Reading "25 = 52" causes me physical pain. Someone please fix the formatting. Original Project Eurler link; http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=9

Comment: @RJFalconer- sorry, didn't notice, added a ^ sign

Comment: Yet you don't care about "32 + 42 = 9 + 16"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to find the `a`, `b`, and `c` such that both `a2 + b2 = c2` and `a + b + c = 1000`. Then you need to output the product `a * b * c`.

Comment: What is the significance of the `a * b * c`? Surely the answer is the `a`, `b` and `c` in themselves and not their product.

Comment: @icio: the nature of the project Euler website is that it one accepts a single number as an answer. If the solution to a problem consists of multiple numbers, the question has to distill the end result to one number somehow.

Comment: Most of the time Project Euler problems use the sum to combine several numbers into one, but in this case the sum is already given in the problem, so they rather arbitrarily chose multiplication. Concatenation would be another option.

Comment: @starblue: And is indeed used. In [#49](http://projecteuler.net/problem=49) for instance :)

Answer (score 8):

These problems are often solvable trivially, if you find the proper insight. The trick here is to use a little algebra before you ever write a loop. I'll give you one hint. Look at the formula to generate pythagorean triples. Can you write the sum of the side lengths in a useful way?

Answer (score 3):

Like a large number of project euler problems, it's all about finding a set of numbers that simultaneously fulfil multiple constraints.

In this case, the constraints are:

1) a^2 + b^2 = c^2

2) a+b+c = 1000

In the early questions the solution can be as simple as nested loops which try each possible combination.